# initialization of variables in C++: = vs {}

Tags: c++

From certain time I've started encounter the following type of initialization from C++11 I think. Instead of the classic '=', now just '{}'. For example, instead of

```
uint32_t count = 0;
```

I find

```
uint32_t count{ 0 };
```

or even

```
uint32_t count{};
```

how is this better to just doing = something? (which I find more readable by the way). I know that now we have in class initialization and others types of initialization but I could not find anything about this particular case.